# Using re.sub capture groups

Tags: python

Apologies for the simple question but Im struggling with this:

```
str = 'EURGBP'

print (re.sub(r'\EUR(GBP)', r'\1', str))
```

returns

```
GBP
```

but

```
print (re.sub(r'\(EUR)(GBP)', r'\2,\1', str))
```

gives me `error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 5`

I am simply trying to capture both elements enclosed in parenthesis and print them out in reversed order using re like this:

```
GBPEUR
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't escape the paren as `\(` means you are literally searching for a `(` in the string so the closing `)` has no matching opening `(`, escaping the `E` worked as you were looking for the literal `E`, also just use `r'\2\1'` unless you want them also separated by a comma:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = 'EURGBP'

In [3]: re.sub(r'(EUR)(GBP)', r'\2\1', s)
Out[3]: 'GBPEUR'
```